# Adding a Custom View as header of ListView

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a custom view (a class extending View) that I'd like to add as a header of List View. Here's the code snippet:

```
    public class MyActivity extends RoboListActivity {
     ...

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.myactivity_apps_header, null);
        getListView().addHeaderView(header);
...more code
}
```

But, I can't see anything. But, when I tried to add a non-custom view, it works. Am I missing something, please guide

**Providing Complete Source Code**

Custom View

```
public class SpaceCustomView extends View {

    private Paint mPaint;
    private Paint mTextPaint;
    private final String mMessage = "Foo Bar";
    private Rect mBounds;


    public StorageSpaceCustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initInput();
    }

    public StorageSpaceCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
        initInput();
    }

    public StorageSpaceCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initInput();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 800, 80, mPaint);
        canvas.drawText(mMessage, 30, 60, mTextPaint);
    }


    private void initInput() {
        mBounds = new Rect();

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        mTextPaint = new Paint();
        mTextPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(20);
        mTextPaint.getTextBounds(mMessage, 0, mMessage.length(), mBounds);
    }

}
```

Header Layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.mycompany.app.view.custom.SpaceCustomView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity Class

```
public class AppsActivity extends RoboListActivity {



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //add header and footer views
        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_apps_header, null);
        getListView().addHeaderView(header);

        View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_pps_footer, null);
        getListView().addFooterView(footer);

        List<AppInfo> applicationList = Mycatalog.getPromotions();

        AppListAdapter adapter = new AppListAdapter(this, applicationList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);


    }


    private class AppListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AppInfo> {
        public AppListAdapter(Activity activity, List<AppInfo> apps) {
            super(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, apps);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty(){
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // if we weren't given a view, inflate one
            if (null == convertView) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater()
                        .inflate(R.layout.activity_uninstall_apps, null);
            }


            return convertView;
        }

    }


}
```

Conclusion: I can see the footer but not the header.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code.  You just inflate your header view and then call `addHeaderView`.  Maybe something wrong in your layout file.

Comment: Would be more clear if you provide all the relevant code, including XML layouts

Answer (score 2):

ListView shows headers and footers only when it's Adapter's `isEmpty()` returns false.
So try setting an adapter that does that...

Comment: Overriding isEmpty (return false) didn't help.